# Select range of rows from record ndarray

Tags: python, select, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I obtained a NumPy record `ndarray` from a CSV file using

```
data = matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec('./data.csv', delimiter=b',')
```

The data set is structured as:

```
      date,a0,a1,a2,a3, b0, b1, b2, b3,[...], b9
2012-01-01, 1, 2, 3, 4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,[...],0.9
```

I want to select (in the SQL sense) just columns `b0` through `b9` from the array, giving the structure

```
 b0, b1, b2, b3,[...], b9
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,[...],0.9
```

The question "[How can I use numpy array indexing to select 2 columns out of a 2D array to select unique values from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178956/how-can-i-use-numpy-array-indexing-to-select-2-columns-out-of-a-2d-array-to-sele)" is similar, but slicing `data[:,5:]` as suggested throws `IndexError: too many indices` with a record array.

Comment: Post more information on structure of your array. It seems to be a shape issue…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have an record array, I think the following will work:

```
data[['b' + str(j) for j in range(10)]]
```

[doc/introduction](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) and  [cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray)

Comment: I had tried `data.dtype.names[5:]`, which says `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10`. It turns out that you have to provide a list, not a tuple as `.dtype.names` gives. So `data[list(data.dtype.names[5:])]`—basically what you've wrote—works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

`data[...,0:3]` will give you columns 0 through 2.

`data[...,[0,2,3]]` will give you columns 0, 2 and 3.

The thing is that you have an array of arrays, while the question you referenced is about 2D-arrays, which is slightly different. See also: [Numpy Array Column Slicing Produces IndexError: invalid index Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093431/numpy-array-column-slicing-produces-indexerror-invalid-index-exception)

Comment: `data[..., 0:3]` gives me *rows* 0 through 2.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail yes, as mentioned in the answer, you actually have a 1D array. Use information on the link provided to create a view, or start using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) to manipulate dataframe like this more easily

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I've double-checked. For me it works, and gives _columns_ 0 through 2.

Comment: @kirelagin: It seems the behavior is different between record arrays and regular arrays.

Comment: Ahh, right, I see. You basically have a 1-D array of tuples. I'm afraid in this case `numpy`'s indexing can't help you…

Comment: do `data = np.asarray(data)` and it will convert your array of tuples -> a 2D array, but I think there is a nicer way to deal with this using the fact that you have a numpy record object.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been answered, but just wanted to log this, as it is related -  it's something between [Extracting specific columns in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386675/extracting-specific-columns-in-numpy-array) and [Select Rows from Numpy Rec Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313806/select-rows-from-numpy-rec-array) (but not quite [How to return a view of several columns in numpy structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182381/how-to-return-a-view-of-several-columns-in-numpy-structured-array) ), this is a syntax I was looking for a while, and I finally found it; let's say this is the data:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1.5, 2.5, (1.0,2.0)), (3.,4.,(4.,5.)), (1.,3.,(2.,6.))],
        dtype=[('x',float), ('y',float), ('value',float,(2,2))])
```

I want something like SQL `SELECT x,value FROM a WHERE y>=3.0` - that is, selecting only certain columns by field names; and only some rows according to some criteria; and the right syntax for that would be:

```
a[['x','value']][a['y']>=3.0]
# [(3.0, [[4.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0]]) (1.0, [[2.0, 6.0], [2.0, 6.0]])]
```

While `a[a['y']>=3.0]` works fine, note that:

```
>>> print a[a['y']>=3.0]['x','value']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

... however, if extra pair of brackets are added, as in `a[a['y']>=3.0][['x','value']]` - all seems to work again.

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!